# How can I get the Face ID system icon programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-x, face-id

Is there a way to get this icon programatically?

[image: Face ID icon]

In some way like this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(someAction)];
```

I've checked [the Icons and Images section in iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/system-icons/), but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: If it's not in the documentation, it's probably unaccessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple **does not encourage** the usage of system icons to identify system authentication features.

From [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/authentication/):

> **Don't use icons to identify system authentication features.** When people see icons that look like the system's Touch ID (thumbprint) and Face ID icons, they think they're supposed to authenticate. Using icons to identify authentication features creates inconsistency and causes confusion, especially when the icons are colorized, displayed at a large size, and presented out of context.

This basically means that there is no way to access the icon with a public API.